# pandas - groupby and select variable amount of random values according to column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, random

Starting from this simple dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'n':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'N':[1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]})
```

I'm trying to select `N` random value from `n` for each `c`. So far I managed to groupby and get one single element / group with:

```
sample = df.groupby('c').apply(lambda x :x.iloc[np.random.randint(0, len(x))])
```

that returns:

```
   N  c  n
c         
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  4
3  2  3  8
```

My expected output would be something like:

```
   N  c  n
c         
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  4
2  2  2  3
3  2  3  8
3  2  3  7
```

so getting 1 sample from c=1 and 2 samples for c=2 and c=3, according to the `N` column.

Comment: Do you assume that every unique value of `c` will have only one unique value of `N`?

Comment: @BrenBarn yes, that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas objects now have a `.sample` method to return a random number of rows:

```
>>> df.groupby('c').apply(lambda g: g.n.sample(g.N.iloc[0]))
c   
1  1    2
2  5    6
   2    3
3  6    7
   7    8
Name: n, dtype: int64
```